# How to install gcc 7 and g++ 7 on NOOBS_v3_2_1 version..?

Tags: noobs, raspberry-pi-desktop

The preinstalled gcc version on Noobs 3_2_1 is 8.3.0. I would like to downgrade or install 7.4.0 version on it.

When i try to run

**sudo apt-get install gcc-7.4**

I get  Below error.

**E: Unable to locate package gcc-7.4 

E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'gcc-7.4' 

E: Couldn't find any package by regex**

How to install gcc 7.4 on noobs 3.2.1 version..?

Comment: Why doesn't the default gcc work for you? Later versions are usually a superset of older junk.

Comment: You **can't** install anything (except an OS) on NOOBS, because it isn't an OS.

Comment: **Raspberry Pi Desktop - a operating system for PC and Mac** has NOTHING to do with the Pi or NOOBS

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have buster installed. As mentioned by @Dougie, there is really no point in using an older version of gcc. However:

Out of the box repos have 7.3:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ apt-cache madison gcc-7
     gcc-7 |   7.3.0-19 | http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf Packages
```

You can install it with `sudo apt-get install gcc-7`